# How to hit an API parallely with different input paramters

Tags: mule, mule-studio, mule-component, mule-el, mule-esb

I am getting  doctorCodes  as (Dr1124914 ,Dr1074955).

My clinic API  gives above response taking one doctorCode a time  ,I have to extract a value from my response.
    But I want to make parallel calls to my API with all values of doctorCodes as shown above in one go , extracting required field from it 
    and accumulating finally to my resultant payload .

*[image: emphasized text]*

Comment: Do you want to perform parallel calls to requestClinicList and accumulate the result in the client Mule flow?

Comment: @AlejandroDobniewski  -  Yes exactly want to perform parallel calls to requestClinicList and accumulate the result in client Mule Flow .

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Scatter-Gather component to perform parallel calls and aggregate the results using DataWeave. See the documentation at https://docs.mulesoft.com/mule-runtime/4.1/scatter-gather-concept

Note that it works for a fixed number of parallel way, not for dynamic routes. I don't think there is no way to do a dynamic number of routes in Mule 4. If you are interested in that you would have to implement it by yourself in custom Java or scripting code somehow.